# There exists a k ∈ N such that for all l > k we have that Q(l) is false (not prime).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

n = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ....}
Q(k) = "k is a prime number"

There exists a k ∈ N such that for all l > k we have that Q(l) is false.

How would I go about proving if this is true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to show
that there is no largest prime?

What would this imply for your question?

Comment: Thanks I used a proof for no largest prime for the question, cheers